# Looking for a web based hierarchical menu editor

Tags: jquery, editor

I'm looking for a web based menu editor that has the following functionality:

- implemented in JavaScript, no postbacks to server side code on each edit
- create menu entries
- edit menu entries
- delete menu entries
- reorganize menu entries
- create sub-menu entries (a hierarchy)
- no hard-connected back-end code
- possibility to load the current menu hierarchy using a custom javascript function
- possibility to persist menu changes on each modification

Menu entry should (at least) exist of title and url.

Editor should (does not have to) provide rendering of the menu. I want to persist the edited hierarchy, and be able to bind a custom menu renderer to the stored hierarchical menu structure.

Any ideas on available editors, either open source or commercial?

Comment: the one from wordpress looks decent, but it's kind of slow and the code is horrible

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on a use case for this?  It seems like something worth writing if a good version doesn't already exist, but I'm not sure exactly what you need.

Comment: "implemented in JavaScript, no postbacks to server side code on each edit" ? do you mean you're going to manually update your website menu on your server ?? i mean i did code a somewhat similar webapp, but at some point you need to hit the save button of the app (which post the new menu) if you want the update to go live

Answer (score 1):

Something like [OpenCube's QuickMenu](http://www.opencube.com/index.asp#)?  
They offer both online and offline menu editors.

Answer (score 1):

Also check [AllWebMenus](http://www.likno.com/allwebmenusinfo.html).